# Fabric UI Megamenu SPFX

Tags: spfx

Would I be able to build a custom menu(preferable mega menu) based on a custom list using the Fabric UI?
Any samples or resources....would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can build a mega menu based on a Custom list using Office Fabric UI.

Basically, you need to create an SPFx extension and then provision it using User Custom action.

Couple of links you can checkout -

Github links - [React mega menu](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-mega-menu)

[Modern sp mega menu](https://github.com/leeroy79/modern-sp-mega-menu)

[React Application tenant global navigation bar](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-application-tenant-global-navbar)

Youtube link to see how this mega menu looks like - [SPFx React mega menu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2773&v=7ZdqLG03PwU)

Comment: Thanks Gautam. But i' after a sample to use the menu that looks exactly like out of the box modern UI nav menu

Comment: check updated answer. Have added a 3rd link which you can customize as per your mega menu requirements to load from a list instead of term store

Comment: Thanks.Also do by any chance know if i can change the fabric ui component Nav to horizontal and not vertical? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#Variants

Comment: not of the top of my head, but i see you can specify css class name as in `<div className='ms-NavExample-LeftPane'>` , so you can modify that for your requirement